# What is the actual share method used by facebook internaly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

As per my knowledge, facebook share can be implemented in 4 or 5 methods/ API calls.

I tried using "feed" method to develop facebook sharing, But found an issue that some details are missing after sharing.

for Example: When using "feed" method when my friend shares a post which I have shared already, Shared post of my friend is having different view than my post.
But Facebook share is showing identical posts even after sharing...!

I need to know, What does Facebook uses for their share option?